# Quartz job thread terminates with no exceptions thrown

Tags: multithreading, spring, threadpool, quartz-scheduler

I am running a scheduled job inside a Java web app with Spring using Quartz that gets executed every 5 minutes. It performs a few queries and sends some mails.
The problem is that after a around 20 queries the thread terminates and no exceptions are thrown.
 The method that is called works perfectly when not called using the scheduler. 
My first guess was that it ran out of time, but I could not find anything in the documentation to back this up.
 Is there a time and/or resource limit associated to each job that I could modify?